# How can I avoid duplicated try catch blocks

Tags: c#, attributes, try-catch

I have several methods that look like this:

```
public void foo()
{
   try 
   {
      doSomething();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      Log.Error(e);
   }
 }
```

Can I change the code to look like?

```
[LogException()]
public void foo()
{   
   doSomething();
}
```

How can I implement this custom attribute? and what are the pros and cons of doing it?

-----Edit 1------------

Can I implemented it myself, I mean just write one class, or do I need to use postsharp or another solution?

Comment: You must implement a custom interceptor based on attributes. Search for this.

Comment: I hope you meant `catch(Exception e)
   {
      Log.Error(e); throw;
   }`

Comment: @Henk I meant without the throw; (I have several methods in the wcf service, I can't throw the exception to the upper level, it will crush my program) what do you suggest?

Comment: It almost seems you were asking for PostSharp website link.

Comment: @Delash, handle only the exceptions you know about. Your current code _is_ crashing, it just doesn't tell the clients.

Comment: Handle the exception at the upper level. I assume your program or its user should know that the WCF service call resulted in an exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use delegates and lambdas:

```
private void ExecuteWithLogging(Action action) {
    try {
        action();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.Error(e);
    }
}

public void fooSimple() {
    ExecuteWithLogging(doSomething);
}

public void fooParameter(int myParameter) {
    ExecuteWithLogging(() => doSomethingElse(myParameter));
}

public void fooComplex(int myParameter) {
    ExecuteWithLogging(() => {
        doSomething();
        doSomethingElse(myParameter);
    });
}
```

In fact, you could rename `ExecuteWithLogging` to something like `ExecuteWebserviceMethod` and add other commonly used stuff, such as checking credentials, opening and closing a database connection, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may try using: [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

or try to google 'AOP' - 'Aspect Oriented Programming'. There are more similar techniques on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you're using WCF you can implement IErrorHandler interface and all exceptions would be routed to your method where you can log them.

- http://www.extremeexperts.com/Net/Articles/ExceptionHandlingInWCF.aspx
- http://codeifollow.blogspot.com/2010/02/wcf-exception-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an AOP approach, a method used at one of my previous employers for common exception handling across a set of class was to have a base class with a method similar to the following

```
    protected TResult DoWrapped<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Do something
            throw;
        }
    }
```

With methods looking like.

```
    public object AMethod(object param)
    {
        return DoWrapped(() =>
                      {
                          // Do stuff
                          object result = param;
                          return result;
                      });
    }
```

Can't remember exactly, it's been a while. But similar to this.