# Implement method decorators in C#

Tags: c#, python, design-patterns, decorator

In `python` is possible to implement `function decorators` to extend the behavior of functions and methods.

In particular I'm migrating a device lib from `python` to `C#`. The communication with device can generate errors which should reraised with custom exception.

In `python` I would write like this:

```
@device_error_wrapper("Device A", "Error while setting output voltage.")   
def set_voltage(self, voltage):
    """
    Safely set the output voltage of device.
    """
    self.__handle.write(":source:voltage:level {0}".format(voltage))
```

This method call would expand to

```
try:
    self.__handle.write(":source:voltage:level {0}".format(voltage))
except Error:
    raise DeviceError("Error while setting output voltage.", "DeviceA")
```

With this pattern you can easily wrap and extend methods without having to write every `try-except` clause in every method.

Is it to possible to implement a similar pattern using `C#`?

If the implementation of the decorator (`device_error_wrapper`) is needed, please tell.

Comment: one alternative I know of is using delegates (example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384228/how-can-i-avoid-duplicated-try-catch-blocks) or you could try postsharp (also mentioned in one of the answers). If it's really possible to use attributes as method decorators for this purpose I don't know (I doubt it but I bet somebody will answer that for you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve something similar using [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). I've only used [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) in the past but it's not free for commercial use though.

There are other AOP solutions out there and you can certainly achieve something similar using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), but it would require more work.

Reza Ahmadi wrote a nice little introduction article called [Aspect Oriented Programming Using C# and PostSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS). It can give you a clear enough idea of what to expect and how it works.

Comment: related to Mono.Cecil. You can take a look Simon Cropp's Fody. Its a nice little plug in that can help you weave prebuilt aspects into your code. It also contains a template to help you build your own aspects.

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, tools like PostSharp allow you to weave in the cross cutting logic during (actually, after) compilation.

The alternative is to do it in runtime. Some IoC tools allow you to define the interceptors which are then added to proxy classes to your implementation. This sounds much more complex then it really is, so I will show an example based on Castle DynamicProxy.

First you define your class which needs to be wrapped.

```
[Interceptor(typeof(SecurityInterceptor))]
public class OrderManagementService : IOrderManagementService
{
    [RequiredPermission(Permissions.CanCreateOrder)]
    public virtual Guid CreateOrder(string orderCode)
    {   
        Order order = new Order(orderCode);
        order.Save(order); // ActiveRecord-like implementation
        return order.Id;
    }
}
```

`RequiredPermission` serves as a decorator here. The class itself is adorned with `Interceptor` attribute specifying the handler for the interface method calls. This can also be put into configuration, so it is hidden from the class.

The interceptor implementation contains the decorator logic

```
class SecurityInterceptor : IMethodInterceptor
{
    public object Intercept(IMethodInvocation invocation, params object[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo method = invocation.Method;
        if (method.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredPermission), true) // method has RequiredPermission attribute
            && GetRequiredPermission(method) != Context.Caller.Permission) {
            throw new SecurityException("No permission!");  
        }

        return invocation.Proceed(args);
    }

    private Permission GetRequiredPermission(MethodInfo method)
    {
         RequiredPermission attribute = (RequiredPermission)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredPermission), false)[0];
        return attribute.Permission;
    }
}
```

There are some drawbacks, however:

- with DynamicProxy you can only wrap interfaces and virtual methods.
- you need to instantiate the object via IoC container and not directly (which is not a problem if you already use IoC container)

Answer (score 2):

There's no **easy** way to implement such decorators in C# - **[custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** are by default only descriptive. There are however projects that extend C# compiler or runtime so that you can actually use this. I think the best one is **[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net)**. With it you can define such method decorator ("aspect" in general) and the method gets wrapped during compilation like you need.

I've also seen this implemented by actually wrapping your classes by decorator classes, but that's **a lot** of work and I don't think it can be done in a really general way. Wikipedia shows this in **[Decorator Pattern article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)**

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you are looking for AOP. PostSharp is a good post compile solution, but [Castle DynamicProxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy-Introduction.ashx) is a runtime AOP solution.